# android: getChildView in ExpandableListView is called 9 times per item

Tags: android, view, expandablelistview

I'm developing an app, using expandableListView, whith a custom adapter. the problem is getChildView is called many times per item. for example for a group with one child, the method is called 9 times.

I'm not sure what code to attach, I'll attach getChildView(), write in the comments if you need another one

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Vehicle vehicle = (Vehicle) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) fragment.getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(fragment.getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        tv.setText(vehicle.getUname().toString());
        //TODO load image
        return convertView;
    }
```

any help will be aprreciated

Comment: that's just ok. If you use view recycling correctly, that woun;t hurt performance

Answer (score 0):

Is `getChilderCount(int groupPosition)` overriden properly?

Should probably be something along the lines of `return getGroup(groupPosition).size()` depending on the type of data you're storing.

Comment: yes it's overriden and it returns the correct value

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue but childView is called only twice. If you have the solution please post it. Thanks!!